# Account Validation Rule

Tags: validation-rule

Why is this validation rule stopping me from editing a new account that I just created 5 minutes ago? It's designed so that only XYorZ profile can create an account *which works,* but it wont let those accounts edit it.

```
AND( DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) = TODAY(),
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e30000001iXXX',
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e13000001xXXX',
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00ea00000021XXX',
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e13000001ZXXX',
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e30000001iXXX',
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e1B000000jXXX',
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e30000001JXXX'
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this rule to only prevent *insert*, then you need to add `ISNEW()` to your criteria:

```
AND(
    ISNEW(),
    DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) = TODAY(),
    ...
)
```

---

## Avoid Hard-Coded Ids

As a general note, your rules will be much easier to read and work with if you filter on `Profile.Name` rather than `ProfileId`. It will also make the rule more portable between orgs (these Id values can change).

**Bad**

```
CreatedBy.ProfileId <> '00e...'
```

**Good**

```
CreatedBy.Profile.Name <> 'Standard User'
```

Comment: Better: `NOT($Permission.Allow_Account_Create)`

Comment: Yes there are plenty of answers on here about the best way to filter certain users in a formula.